# NodeJS memory leak with buffers

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, server, buffer

I have a NodeJS server running and the memory consumption of it is increasing every day.

I searched the internet to find out where the problem came from, so I used the node-heapdump module to analyze the memory.

The size of the file at the start of the server was almost the same as what I took after a few days while PM2 tells me a clear increase in the memory used.

Subsequently I knew that the buffers were stored outside the heap of V8 "A Buffer is similar to an array of integers but corresponds to a raw memory allocation outside the V8 heap" so I guess my memory leak problem come from the fact that I use a lot of buffer and it is the case.

The problem is that I think I know exactly in which file the problem is but I do not know how to solve it.

Here is the code of the file https://hastebin.com/apicituleb.js

This is an example of the result of the "creatImage" function
[image]

The module "ressourcesManager" contains all the resources I need in my application so a lot of buffer but I do not think the problem comes from because I load them once at startup.
The module code "ressourcesManager" is pretty rough but here is the code if you want to take a look https://hastebin.com/neyanuhema.php

It's been a while since I have this problem that I can not solve so if people want to spend a little time to help me I will be very grateful.

PS: If you want heap snapshot files here they are:

Start:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LDwk8y3cygGDrSr1z8xV__PboWiEtQHt

End:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1s4WXgia2CM4rb3fd6wCdVxOLgiS9Oahz

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [node-oom-heapdump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-oom-heapdump) module can help? It offers the same functionality as node-heapdump, but it also automatically creates a heapdump when an out of memory is about to happen (which is the most interesting moment to have a heapdump of). Maybe this heapdump can give more insight?